# how to setup 2 physical server into 1 server

Tags: cluster

i need help on where to start and how to combine 2 physical servers to make it function as 1 server.  what i'm trying to do here is that we need a 2x quad-core server to be set-up as our SQL server, however, the only available server in our place is a single core so we are planning to buy 2 servers and eventually combine them to function as one, will that be possible? if it does, what are the softwares that I need and how should i do it? sorry guys, this is very new to me, your help is very much appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this a compute cluster (combine the power of 2) or a failover cluster (one carries on if the other breaks) ? Sounds like a compute, but just checking.

Comment: hey guys, thanks for replying in my query.

@sirex - in my understanding with cluster, what we are trying to do is to combine the computing power of the 2 physical server.

@chopper3 - we already have the 2 physical server in our office and what we are trying to do is to combine their computing power and function as our MSSQL Server.  Thanks again in advance.

Answer (score 5):

You don't mention which particular SQL engine you currently use or wish to use in the future but people generally cluster servers for only two reasons; to overcome performance limits of their existing hardware and to provide higher availability.

I suspect that you wish to cluster simply because you need higher performance, not for higher availability - if this is the case and you're using either MSSQL or Oracle then I would strongly suggest that due to the relatively cheap cost of modern hardware it will be cheaper and quicker to simply buy higher performance hardware than to buy the additional software and licences required to do this in a clustered environment. Of course these costs are unavoidable if you're trying to achieve higher availability.

If you're using another SQL engine you'd need to tell us what that is for us to help you to decide.

Comment: @dex, following your updated comment you really only have on choice which is to cluster your MSSQL servers - this is very common practice but costs money and doesn't not make both your machines act as one as such.